# React positioning components dynamically using screen resolution

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, position, css-position

I am trying to create a landing page for a restaurant. I have created the background image on which I want to display my components. my goal is that with any screen, the positions of the components will be the same - image of the goal in the end. I have several issues:

1. I got the social icons to position and resize in relation with the screen's dimensions, but I can't get the logic right so that they will be fixed in the same place.
2. I half-managed to resize the Paper components dynamically but I couldn't figure out how to move them to the left/right as I did with the SocialIcons. Moreover, I want to create a space between them, and playing with inspect item in the browser I know I need to insert display:'inline-grid' somewhere but couldn't figure out where.

**[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-cori-hkxv3?file=/src/App.js)**

**LandingPage.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import ButtonGroup from "@mui/material/ButtonGroup";
import backgroundImage from "./BennyBackground.jpg";
import { SocialIcon } from "react-social-icons";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const LandingPage = () => {
  const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();

  const CustomPaper = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
    color: theme.primary.text,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    borderRadius: 80,
    letterSpacing: 1,
    height: height / 13,
    width: width / 7,
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: theme.primary.main,
    "&.Mui-checked": {
      color: theme.primary.main
    },
    ":hover": {
      cursor: "pointer"
    }
  }));

  const theme = createTheme({
    primary: {
      main: "#e8bf01",
      text: "black"
    },
    typography: {
      fontFamily: ["Miriam Libre"]
    }
  });

  function getWindowDimensions() {
    const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
    return {
      width,
      height
    };
  }

  function useWindowDimensions() {
    const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(
      getWindowDimensions()
    );

    useEffect(() => {
      function handleResize() {
        setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
      }

      window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
      return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, []);
    // console.log(windowDimensions);
    return windowDimensions;
  }

  return (
    <Grid
      container
      xs={12}
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
        backgroundPosition: "top",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100vw",
        overflow: "auto"
      }}
    >
      <Grid container justifyContent="center">
        <ButtonGroup orientation="vertical" sx={{ gap: 1 }}>
          <SocialIcon
            style={{ height: height / 12, width: height / 12, left: width / 4 }}
            url="https://www.tiktok.com/@bennysburger"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            bgColor="white"
          />
          <SocialIcon
            style={{ height: height / 12, width: height / 12, left: width / 4 }}
            url="https://www.facebook.com/Bennys.Burger.diner/"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          />
          <SocialIcon
            style={{ height: height / 12, width: height / 12, left: width / 4 }}
            url="https://instagram.com/bennysburgerdiner"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          />
        </ButtonGroup>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container justifyContent="center" >
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Typography theme={theme}>
            <Grid item>
              <CustomPaper>Orders</CustomPaper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <CustomPaper>Menu</CustomPaper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <CustomPaper>Gallery</CustomPaper>
            </Grid>
          </Typography>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default LandingPage;
```

My goal is fixed center positioning of the components (don't mind that the rest of the image isn't shown if the screen width is too small), the social icons on the top-right, and the papers on the left with spacing between them, dynamically sized and positioned with the screen's dimensions as such:

**[image: My Goal]**

I would highly appreciate any solutions or ideas you might have!

Comment: Positioning on the screen does not work the same way as positioning on a bg image, they scale differently. You're better off positioning on an actual inline image - Something like https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Comment: @Paulie_D Could you please elaborate on this technique and how to implement it with React?

Comment: I have no knowledge of react.